# Касательно языковых рекордов

Tags: общие-вопросы

Есть такое понятие "языковой рекорд". К примеру: самое длинное предложение на русском языке, рассказ, где все слова начинаются на одну и ту же букву, самое длинное слово и тому подобные достижения. Собственно, вопрос: а где храниться информация о подобном? Существует ли реестр таких рекордов? Регистрируются ли они официально? Если да, то каким образом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё в той же Книге рекордов Гиннесса

http://speakrus.ru/articles/guinlang.htm